# JavaScript array is NaN? AngularJS ngModel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to see what the value of an ngModel is:

```
.directive('myDir', function() {
  return {
    require: '?ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {
      if (!ngModel)
        return

      console.log(ngModel)
      console.log(ngModel.$modelValue)
    }
  };
})
```

Even though my ngModel is an array it logs NaN?

[image: What's going on here?]

Comment: I had this exact same problem recently and gave up. Instead of using `require` and the 4th param in `link`, I just used `scope: { ngModel: "=" }`, and was able to change `scope.ngModel` in the `link` function

Comment: ? - Attempt to locate the required controller or pass null to the link fn if not found. -- You're attempting to pass in an ngModel, not a controller.

Comment: @mortsahl Sorry I don't understand your comment at all.

Comment: @Ian thanks for describing your experiences.

Comment: Use require to locate a controller, not a model

Comment: @mortsahl isn't it a common usecase to require ngModel? Is it wrong in this case?

Comment: See the documentation for require at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***$viewValue*** and ***$modelValue*** default to `Number.NaN` -- JavaScript Definition for Not - a - Number.

check **[Github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1515)** and you find that

```
var NgModelController = ['$scope', '$exceptionHandler', '$attrs', 
                                 '$element', '$parse',
'$animate', '$timeout',
    function($scope, $exceptionHandler, $attr, $element, $parse, 
                   $animate, $timeout) 
  {
  this.$viewValue = Number.NaN;
  this.$modelValue = Number.NaN;
```

Why is this convienient? Because ***AngularJS*** tries to avoid having cases like `null` and `undefined`. View Values and Model Values are bound and defined by "scope". That's the point of the $scope service -- to manage the modelValue and viewValue.

Until an ***AngularJS*** service accesses them, they are defaulted to `number.NaN`

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why the modelvalue is set so late?

Comment: @harry its the frameworks nature to wait until referenced for a model. A typical app is likely to have numerous viewmodels at any given time. Many of them will overlap across a block of data. That's what you're loggimg to your console -- a reference to a block of data. A model is shaped from data when referenced by a service in controller scope. This makes sense when you consider that the model depends on scope of controller requesting it. An event must trigger the digesy cycle

Answer (score 2):

Presumably when you log `ngModel` initially, `ngModel.$modelValue` really is `NaN`.  Then you log `ngModel.$modelValue` and you see it. Then various watchers and so on run, changing `ngModel.$modelValue` to the array in question. Then you open the console-logged object (which you logged by reference, and which will therefore reflect changes) and see the changed value.

You can reproduce this easily in your console:

```
var s = {
    some: 1,
    big: [ 1, 2, 3 ],
    object: [ "that gets a little drop-down arrow next to it when you log" ]
}
console.log(s);
s.some = "Changed!";
```

Click the dropdown next to the initial log and note that `s.some` shows `"Changed!"` instead of `1`, whereas the text next to the initial log remains `1`, as in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the specifics of Angular.js, but based on your screenshot and code I can offer an educated guess.

On the top line of the screenshot, an Object has been logged. The "preview" of that object (the not-expanded part) shows `$modelValue: NaN`. The same `NaN` is logged when you do `console.log(ngModel.$modelValue)`. So at the instant that you log it, the value is `NaN`.

For your object preview, hover over the little blue "i" icon and it will tell you "Object state is captured upon first expansion". That means that the state of the object might change some time between when you log it and when you expand it.

What I gather from this is that your `ngModel` is initialized in some sort of "blank" state. You log it in that blank state, and see `NaN`. Then something else changes it, then you expand it to see the `$modelValue` is an array.