# Angular: how to get first $viewValue value without parsers and watchers?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to make a rule for input, for example when the value is `0` then something, but default `$viewValue` is `NaN`.
How to get a real value?

I can't use `$watch` or `$parse` because I need to use only first value of my input and activate my rule.

```
return {
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {

            console.log(ngModelCtrl);  // says that $viewValue exists
            console.log(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue); // says it's NaN
```

HTML

```
 {{metters.test = 0}}
<input type="text" ng-model="metters.test" mydirective>
```

Console.log

```
ngModelCtrl $viewValue :  NaN
ngModelCtrl $modelValue :  NaN

ngModelCtrl :  e.i…e.c {
$viewValue: NaN, 
$modelValue: NaN, 
$parsers: Array[0], 
$formatters: Array[0],
$modelValue: 0
$viewValue: 0
.... }
```

Comment: sorry for that, have just added

Comment: it's written in comments. in first situation when you open ngModelCtrl you can see $viewValue = 0. in second situation onsole.log(ngModelCtrl.$viewValue  ) is 'NaN'

Comment: I've just saw that there is two different values in the 'ngModelCtrl', first is NaN, and the second is my number value. I've added a console log to my post. please see

Comment: OK, so this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087888/javascript-array-is-nan-angularjs-ngmodel explains the **NaN**. It looks like you need a watcher to get the initial value http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18458383/angularjs-read-initial-value-of-ngmodel-viewvalue-from-different-directive. Good luck!